# This is NOT a Description of my Question, But Stackoverflow Did NOT allow me to submit My Descriptive Title

Tags: excel, error-handling, runtime-error

REAL Title: EXCEL VBA: How to Handle Overflow Error

I have a calculation in a EXCEL macro program, which, in some cases resolves to a number larger than EXCEL can handle. For example:

EXP(772.570555209417)

Can someone suggest the best way to handle this error? I have tried:

```
    If IsError(Exp(n_beta(i, 1) + Abs(WorksheetFunction.Norm_Inv((1 - Conl / 100) / 2, 0, 1)) * logSTDERR(i))) Then
        MsgBox ("Error!!")
        Exit Sub
    End If
```

In the case above:

```
n_beta(i, 1) + Abs(WorksheetFunction.Norm_Inv((1 - Conl / 100) / 2, 0, 1)) * logSTDERR(i))
```

resolves to 772.570555209417. However, when I run this code, I receive the Overflow error on the IsError() statement (Highlighted in yellow below from the VBA Editor):

[image]

Any assistance or insight is appreciated.

Comment: What is the value of `Con1`?  What line does your code stop on when returning the error?  Please post your data and code as TEXT.  Very hard to paste pictures into the VBA editor.

Comment: Sorry: Conl resolves to .95. Furthermore, Abs = 1.95996... above is the value of Abs(WorksheetFunction.Norm_Inv((1 - Conl / 100) / 2, 0, 1)). The code and data are much too large to post in their entirety. Thanks for the clarifying questions!!

Comment: Unfortunately, what you have posted does not allow me to reproduce your problem. In addition to what I have already asked, I also have no idea of the code underlying your `logSTDERRR` function. Also, I assume you are aware that it is not possible for `ORLB` or `ORUB` to contain a decimal value, but you might be looking for rounded integer results (and that wouldn't cause this problem). If you want to continue, take a look at [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and edit your question to provide more information.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. This has helped me clarify the question. I have reverted back to my original code and edited the question to reflect these changes.

Comment: @Dan posting _only_ images of code is useless (and considered rude, since it forces us to retype your code.  Or mre likely just ignore your Q) .  Please update your Q to include the code _as text_ (you can also include images if you consider they add value)

Comment: @Dan it might be a typo: Your equation takes `Exp( the whole expression )` which contradicts the implied intent from your sample values.

Comment: @Chris Thanks for the feedback. You are correct: I was breaking the calculations down incorrectly, which was misleading in my post. The correct calculation is to take Exp( the whole expression) which does trigger the error message in both cases. I am revising the question now.

Comment: @Dan.  Your variables are of type `Variant/Double` ( [see here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/data-types/double-data-type) ).  These can hold a max positive value of `1.79769313486231570E+308` .  When doing an `Exp(x)` Double will overflow when x > approx 710.  If you truly need to calculate a value this large you'll need a different approach.  Without much more context I can't reccomend one.

Comment: @Dan maybe what you are looking for is [`On Error ...`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/on-error-statement) and [Err](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/err-object)

Comment: To expand on @chrisneilsen stmt, `IsError` checks for the Excel error values (`#N/A`, `#VALUE!`, `#REF!`, `#DIV/0!`, `#NUM!`, `#NAME?` or `#NUL`).  `OnError …` checks for VBA run-time errors.  So the latter is what you would use in this instance..

Answer (score 0):

For those interested: With the help of Chris and Ron, I developed this code to obviate the "Run-time error '6' Overflow" error:

```
LNORUB = n_beta(i, 1) + Abs(WorksheetFunction.Norm_Inv((1 - Conl / 100) / 2, 0, 1)) * logSTDERR(i)

If LNORUB > 709.5 Then
    MsgBox ("Error!!: Message to the User...")
    End
End If

ORUB = Exp(LNORUB)
```

I believe that Ron was correct: The On Error statement would have also been an option, however, in my case, because it was the exponentiation that was causing the super large number, I was able to catch this eventuality before it occurred and therefore avoid the Overflow error altogether.

Many thanks to Chris and Ron!!